# how to specify google maps launch mode in android

Tags: android, parameters, maps, launch

Hi I have a task to launch the maps app to get directions from point A to point B.

The requirement is to have the maps open the step-by-step (textual list) view rather than the maps - like

1. Start here
2. turn left
3. turn right ...
   .......
   so on.

See this link to the screenshot
http://i562.photobucket.com/albums/ss65/nar_karapetyan/device-2011-10-24-113823.png

Is there a parameter that I can use to specify which mode I'd like the maps to launch in?

(Basically there's a button at the bottom-left corner on the maps to bring up that view once directions are available, but I'd like the maps to show that view automatically when launched.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no official API to launch the google navigation (from an Intent that is) at the moment. If you'd like to see some potential work-arounds, checkout this [stackoverflow post (Intent to start a navigation activity)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801684/intent-to-start-a-navigation-activity) which is highly related to your question.