# How can I send an intent to navigation with multiple waypoints?

Tags: android, android-intent, gps, navigation

I have an app, and in my app I need to be able to send an intent to start navigation.  In that intent, I need to have the start geopoint (or lat lon), multiple way points (as geopoints or lat lon), and then an end (as geopoints or lat lon).  I know how to send the intent to do everything except the waypoints.  I really need the format of the string that I would be sending to navigation.

Answer (score 0):

```
There isn't a standard Intent URI for navigation.
```

see this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801684/intent-to-start-a-navigation-activity).

Comment: Ok I checked that link out, but I guess I didnt explain my question well enough.  I need to know the actual URI or syntax I would use to add a start, end, and waypoints/stops in between there.  I have a bunch of coordinates that I need to use in the navigation.  I dont just want them to get from a to b anyway they can, I want them to use the waypoints.  What would be the syntax for that URI.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the US, you could use an unofficial way (I don't recommend using it though since it's not official). This will launch Google Maps in navigation mode.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
    Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=an+address+city");
```