# Android Map search for an address

Tags: android, google-maps

In my Android application I am working with Google Maps, where I want to search for a particular address for example "Apple Office". So I found the current location and need to search for "Apple Office" within five km of the current position. So my address is already marked in Google Maps. I know how to search for a location

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:37.7749,-122.4194");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(mapIntent);
}
```

This will search for San Francisco... but I need to search with text. So what change do I need for that?

Comment: checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/21557967/1921263 and also this one.http://stackoverflow.com/a/15872289/1921263

Comment: thanks let me check...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use '**Google Places API for Android**'. https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/

Comment: Ok. Did you try the Place autocomplete feature?

Comment: follow the url I have already posted. You can find samples there.