# Is there a way to intent all navigation apps in phone

Tags: google-maps, android-intent

I'm developing an app and I need to intent from my app to installed navigation apps. Found some useful resources but they are not useful for my approach.

[Launching Google Maps Directions via an intent on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662531/launching-google-maps-directions-via-an-intent-on-android)

- This example only works with Google Navigation

[Intent to start a navigation activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801684/intent-to-start-a-navigation-activity)

- This example is not working

My whole aim is; imagine one person's smartphone s/he have yandex navi, google maps and sygic navi. When I click to navigation button on the developed app, this app prompt user to select an application for navigation.

How can I do this

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, I will start with the idea of using `Intent` and let the Android framework offer the choice to users by an appropriate prompt. For a start, look at Google link @ [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents).
A difference is that I would not call setPackage().
Suggested code:

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:37.7749,-122.4194");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Notes:

- setPackage() is not called.
- Uri.parse() is using sample coordinates.

Comment: Correct answer, I installed Waze and Google Map, it offers the choice when using this code.